# Catch an uploaded csv file using Django (No models, No forms)

Tags: python, django, csv, file-upload

I am failing to catch this uploaded csv file. I just want to upload a file, and store into a variable so I can use it later.

#### template.html

```html
{% block content %}
                <h1>File content</h1>
                <form action="{% url 'plot:printInfo' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                     {% csrf_token %}
                    <input id="uploadbutton" type="file" value="Browse" name="file" accept="text/csv" /><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
                </form>
            {% endblock %}
```

#### views.py

```
def printInfo(request):
    #PATH = '/Users/xxxxx_000/Desktop/Django/mysqlApp/plot/data/'
    #data = pd.read_csv(PATH + 'SalesJan2009.csv')


    csvfile = request.FILES['file']

    data = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    html = data.to_html()

    #method implemented below, It allows to add Id field to an HTML table
    finalString = addIdToHtml(html)

    context = {'TableOfData': finalString,}

    #x and y are lists
    return render(request, 'filter.html', context)
```

When I use

```
data = pd.read_csv(PATH + 'SalesJan2009.csv')
```

it works pretty fine. Now all I want to do is to replace 'SalesJan2009.csv' by an uploaded file.  How do I do that?

Comment: what is returning `request.FILES['file']` ?

Comment: if you are not using models and if you are not using forms ,why are you using django??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using `pandas`.. If you need to replace file content, try following:

```
def printInfo(request):
    path = '/Users/xxxxx_000/Desktop/Django/mysqlApp/plot/data/'
    # data = pd.read_csv(PATH + 'SalesJan2009.csv')
    csvfile = request.FILES['file']

    data = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    html = data.to_html()

    finalString = addIdToHtml(html)
    context = {
        'TableOfData': finalString,
    }

    file_name = path + 'SalesJan2009.csv'
    data.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')

    return render(request, 'filter.html', context)
```

Please note, that existing `SalesJan2009.csv` file will be erased and populated with new data. You'll need to do some validation for it(new data) before saving.

Comment: I'd actually like to retrieve an _uploaded csv file_ so I can use it in place of 'SalesJan2009.csv'

Comment: @NabilJunior Then can you please paste an error that you have? In your example: data = read_csv(csvfile) should actually read file that you uploaded to your server.

Comment: for instance, I test by using UploadedFile.size, but It doesn't print anything

Comment: @NabilJunior what output do you have for print(csvfile) ?